# Static Table vs Dynamic Prototype for a Table with many (100+ items)

Tags: ios, xcode, dynamic, static, tableview

I'm relatively new to iOS and Xcode, so please forgive if the question seems stupid. I just couldn't get an answer through extensive searching.

I'm building an app that requires a tableView with 100+ items split into 6 or 7 sections, each list item with a checkbox accessory. As I understand, for my needs, a static table is adequate. However, with such a large list, would it be expensive in terms of resources compared to a dynamic prototype, where the program recycles the table slots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No stupid questions.

You should definitely use dequeued cells “recycled” as you say instead of static.

It’s best practice.

It’s trivially easy to do, with registering a nib for reuse.

Good article on this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uitableviewcell-reuse.

Comment: Great, thanks! and thanks for the website too, going to read up a lot.

Comment: My pleasure. Also check this out bro https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-using-the-wrong-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier/